# run git bash inside windows container

Tags: windows, docker, git-bash

I install Git for Windows and git bash inside my container.

When I exec into it though and try to run sh.exe or bash.exe it looks like it tries to open it but then exits.

Not sure what is preventing this from working in a container. I like the ability to run git bash inside the windows container.

I mostly just want to be able to run it inside the container but would also but useful to use it as entry point:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh.exe mycontainer
```

Comment: Can you post dockerfile

Comment: How did you install Git for Windows and git bash inside a container?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue and widely discussed in 
[msys2](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/1239)
and
[git bash](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1659)

where has a workaround like below:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse c:\MinGit c:\MinGit_copy
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse c:\MinGit
Rename-Item c:\MinGit_copy c:\MinGit
c:\MinGit\usr\bin\ssh.exe -V
```

where `c:\MinGit` may also be `msys64` in your case

which works on my scenario. This should be a bug for msys2

Comment: on the rename step I get "Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name."